# change the plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

When a figure is created in MATLAB ,
Is it possible to change that shape?

Can I make such changes in the figure window?
For example, I want to change the position of some nodes, or change the color of the arrows.
Some angles are large, for example, in my shape

[image: Shape],

the angle between 5, 7 and 12 is enlarged and I want to be smaller.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.graphplot-properties.html